# C# Асинхронное подключение к нескольким SerialPort

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await, task

Проект делаю на Unity 2018.3.10. Скрипты на С#.

Имеется самодельное устройство подключенное к USB и определяемое ОС как подключенное в COM-порт. Устройство шлёт ключевую последовательность из 3 байт, а затем набор данных. Поскольку в компиляторе Unity у класса SerialPort не реализован `event` на принятие данных, пришлось в ручную создавать отдельный поток и читать данные приходящие из буфера. Порт для подключения брал из диспетчера устройств и задавал вручную.

Решив автоматизировать процесс начал подключаться к каждому порту и в течении одной секунды ожидать ключевой последовательности. Если последовательность приходила, то добавлять порт в список устройств, если не было то пропускать, и в любом случае я закрывал подключение. На выходе этого метода имел список портов к которым подключены мои устройства.

Весь этот процесс сильно тормозит UI, потому что я по очереди подключаюсь ко всем портам, и для каждого создаю поток чтения данных, а поток работает в течении секунды, а я ожидаю завершения работы всех потоков. В  общем это долго!

Недавно познакомился с `Task`, `async` и `await`, но не разобрался ещё до конца.
Думается что `Task`-и мне подойдут больше, чем отдельный несколько потоков, да ещё и запускающихся последовательно.

Прошу помочь, т.е. подсказать как реализовать асинхронное подключение сразу к нескольким портам, определить есть на этом порту моё устройство или нету и в конце вернуть список портов с устройствами.

По сути вопрос: Как одновременно запустить несколько задач внутри которых будет выполняться мой метод подключения и проверки, а затем вернуть результат?

**Сейчас выглядит это примерно так:**

`SerialThread` - класс который содержит в себе метод с циклом `while(true){}` в котором происходит чтение байт из буфера порта.

`Connect(out sT, out T, name)` - метод для инициализации и запуска потока.

```
private List<string> GetPortListWithDevices() {                
    var spNames = new List<string>(SerialPort.GetPortNames());  
    if (spNames.Count == 0) return spNames;

    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    try {
        timer.Elapsed += delegate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args) {
                ((System.Timers.Timer) sender).Enabled = false;
            };
        var result = new List<string>();
        foreach (var name in spNames) {
        SerialThread sT = null;
        Thread T = null;
            try {
                Connect(out sT, out T, name);
                timer.Enabled = true;
                timer.Start();
                while (timer.Enabled) {
                    // Ждём.....
                }
                if (sT.isDevice)
                    result.Add(name);
                else Debug.LogWarning($"SP ({name}) is not Digitizer");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Debug.LogWarning($"SP ({name}) not added to list");
            }
            finally {
                Disconnect(ref sT, ref T);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.LogException(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

**UPD:** метод `Connect()`

```
private static bool Connect(out SerialThread sT, out Thread T, string portName, int baudRate = 38400) {
    try {
        sT = new SerialThread(portName, baudRate, _reconnectionDelay, maxUnreadMessages);
        T = new Thread(sT.RunForever) {Name = portName};
        T.Start();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.LogException(e);
        sT = null;
        T = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: а метод Connect можно добавить к задаче?

Comment: @pashagoroshko, добавил метод

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:** Не совсем понятно, чего мы ожидаем от метода **RunForever** класса **SerialThread**, но я предположил что он выглядит так:

```
    public bool IsDevice { get; set; }
    public string PortName { get; set; }
    public void RunForever(string portName)
    {
        while(/*true*/)
        {
            IsDevice = true;
        }
    }
```

Тогда код будет примерно таким:

```
    private async Task<SerialThread> ConnectAsync(string portName, int baudRate = 38400)
    {
        var serialThread = new SerialThread(portName, baudRate, _reconnectionDelay, maxUnreadMessages);

        await Task.Run(() => serialThread.RunForever(portName));

        return serialThread;
    }
```

Обратится можно так

```
    private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetPortListWithDevicesAsync()
    {
        var spNames = new List<string>(SerialPort.GetPortNames());

        return spNames.AsParallel()
            .Select(async x => await ConnectAsync(x, baudRate: 123))
            .Select(x => x.Result)
            .Where(x => x.IsDevice)
            .Select(x=>x.PortName)
            .ToArray();
    }
```

Или так:

```
    private IEnumerable<string> GetPortListWithDevices()
    {
        var spNames = new List<string>(SerialPort.GetPortNames());
        var tasks = spNames.Select(x => ConnectAsync(x, baudRate: 123)).ToArray();

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        return tasks.Select(x => x.Result)
            .Where(x => x.IsDevice)
            .Select(x => x.PortName);
    }
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, мой SerialThread основан на [этом](https://github.com/dwilches/Ardity/blob/master/UnityProject/Assets/Ardity/Scripts/Threads/AbstractSerialThread.cs) классе, просто чуточку переписан под мои задачи

Comment: @GoodSimon, исправил